# How to customize context menu of Slack windows client?

Tags: contextmenu, slack, windows-client

Im trying to build custom context menu for slack. But, the [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/) page doesn't contain any information about customizing user interface.

Currently Slack displays only 2 options:
[image]

Is it a known restriction? If not can anyone please let me know where to start to build the custom context menu for Slack windows client?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not something you can do to my knowledge. Slack is made to run on many different platform incl. mobiles, so I would not expect them to ever provide this feature.

Comment: Thank you. One workaround im following is to use Slack in browser where I have the custom contextmenu add-on installed. Also, using Slack in browser reduces the memory consumption in overall.